# rails with datatables multi select does not seem to be recognized

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

This is just my lack of understanding how the Rails DataTable Gem and the DataTable JS extras work together.

I am just trying to do multi select in my datable I am using the gem. (GemList Below)

```
jquery-datatables-rails (3.4.0, 3.3.0)
jquery-rails (4.0.5, 4.0.4)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
```

Data Tables works fine but now I'm trying to use multi select by column for the first time and that seems to need

"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"

Just following this code example

https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html

My application.js is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.buttons
//= require buttons.print.min
//= require buttons.html5.min
//= require buttons.flash.min
//= require_tree .
```

I did move jquery.dataTables.min.js  into my assets javascript directory but I am not sure what else is needed for that to work?

Here is my datable method.  Everything works except it does not do the select so I am assuming I need to do something else with the JS file.

```
/* testing area
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    var events = $('#events');
    var table = $('#combined_table').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        select: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Get selected data',
                action: function () {
                    var count = table.rows( { selected: true } ).count();

                    events.prepend( '<div>'+count+' row(s) selected</div>' );
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Should everything just work or do I need to somehow let rails know that JS file is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/css/select.bootstrap.css"/>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/js/dataTables.select.js"></script>
```

and because you want multi-select

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var events = $('#events');
    var table = $('#combined_table').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        select: {style:"multi"},
        buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Get selected data',
            action: function () {
                var count = table.rows( { selected: true } ).count();

                events.prepend( '<div>'+count+' row(s) selected</div>' );
            }
        }
    ]
} );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks this worked I did not realize I had to had the <script> tags I thought rails would somehow load the javascript from assets and the data tables gem would somehow use it.  I guess not :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach based on toggling CSS class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var events = $('#events');
    var table = $('#combined_table').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Get selected data',
            action: function () {
                var count = table.rows('.selected').data().length;
                events.prepend('<div>' + count + ' row(s) selected</div>');
            }
        }]
   });

    $('#combined_table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

});
```